# Could someone please define an Engine in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

In computing terms, an engine is something that is continually producing output based on input. But in Ruby, the term seems a little bit loose. The people who've created Refinery CMS have taken to calling gems that extend the functionality of their system, 'engines'.

Basically, what I want to know is, is Spree, the open source ecommerce cms written in ruby, an engine? Would calling it the 'spree engine' be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As defined by Rails, an Engine is a lot like an application within an application. Spree is one of these, and there are others. Each engine has its own `app` folder with the same sort of structure you'd see in a top-level application.

You can combine one or more engines together into an application, then add your own functionality on top. That's what makes systems like Spree far more flexible than a fixed-puropose Rails app that you have limited control over.

Things that extend Rails are only truly engines if they are self-contained applications. Many gems add functionality that's much more specific than that, so are better termed "plug-ins" or "modules" depending on the phrasing.

It's actually pretty easy to build your own engine and can be useful for separating and re-using code across several different applications.

Comment: Concise and informative! Cleared up the jargon as well as important RoR concepts, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is quite good explanation in guide [Getting Started with Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).

Answer (score 2):

Spree is actually comprised of many engines...

The overcooked version: Engines come kitted with (many of) the guts of a typical rails application, with a few bonuses: namespacing out of the box, generators for easily copying migrations, and the ability to mount it in another rails application.

Answer (score 1):

From  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

1 What are engines?

Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide functionality to their host applications. A Rails application is actually just a "supercharged" engine, with the Rails::Application class inheriting a lot of its behavior from Rails::Engine.

Try to read this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html and also this cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines